# How to show different layouts in each Tab in a TabLayout using Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I have been trying to show different layouts in different tabs in the swipeable TabLayout using PagerTabStrip. Can anybody help?

I want to show one layout in first tab, second different layout in 2nd tab etc.

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {


// create object of FragmentPagerAdapter
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

// viewpager to display pages
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the five
    // primary sections of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

}

/**
 * A FragmentPagerAdapter that returns a fragment corresponding to one of
 * the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
        case 0: {
            //Show 1st Layout(Here I need HELP)

             //HELP HELP HELP

        }case 1:
        {
            //Show 2nd Layout(Here I need HELP)

             //HELP HELP HELP
        } 
        default:
        }
        Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 5 total pages.
        return 6;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "Section 1";
        case 1:
            return "Section 2";
        case 2:
            return "Section 3";
        case 3:
            return "Section 4";
        case 4:
            return "Section 5";
        case 5:
            return "Section 6";
        }
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
 * displays dummy text.
 */
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Create a new TextView and set its text to the fragment's section
        // number argument value.
        TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setTextSize(25);
        textView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
                ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return textView;
    }
   }

 }
```

Comment: Just change what your fragment is. In onCreateView do something like `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.whatever_layout_you_want, container, false);`, do whatever you need to with that view like set TextViews, add listeners to Buttons, etc., and then instead of returning textView, return the inflated `view`. You can set the arguments of the fragment to the position of the tab on instantiation and use that position from the arguments in a switch to determine what layout to inflate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 View rootView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        switch (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER))
        {
            case 1: {
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bba, container, false);
                break;
            }
            case 2: {
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bcom, container, false);
                break;
            }

            case 3: {
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bca, container, false);
                break;
            }

        }
        return rootView;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok for the people who want to solve this problem using design patterns.
 Find full working solution [Here](https://github.com/rohitksingh/TabLayout).

If u write the fragment based on if-else condition it may solve the problem

```
switch(fragmentId)
    {
    case 1:
    {
      fragment 1 related stuff
    }
    case 2:
    {
    fragment 2 related stuff
    }
    .......
    .......
    and so on
```

But the problem with this approach is if in future,

> 1) you decide to add more fragments

or

> 2) you decide to change some functionality of existing fragment

Then you will have to modify the existing code (inside if-else condition)
Not a preferred programming practice

Instead you can follow this approach

```
public abstract class BasicFragment extends Fragment {

public BasicFragment newInstance()
{
    Log.d("Rohit", "new Instance");
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
   // args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
    BasicFragment fragment = provideYourFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;

}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanseState)
{
    View view = provideYourFragmentView(inflater,parent,savedInstanseState);
    return view;
}

public abstract BasicFragment provideYourFragment();

public abstract View provideYourFragmentView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState);
}
```

> Your Fragment implementation

```
public class ImageFragment extends BasicFragment{
@Override
public BasicFragment provideYourFragment() {

    return new ImageFragment();
}

@Override
public View provideYourFragmentView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_fragment,parent,false);

    //Get your parent layout of fragment
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)view;

    //Now specific components here

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)layout.findViewById(R.id.myImage);
    imageView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);

    return view;

}
}
```

Happy coding