# Put code in Activity or Fragment to handle orientation change?

Tags: android, android-layout, fragment

I have an Activity and two Fragment layouts and classes.
All I need to do is that when I change the screen orientation, reorganize the same content differently.

My question is where should I put my code?
Which class Activity class or Fragment class?

If I code in Fragment class, should I put code in both classes, or if I use main Activity, how would I find objects (like TextViews) from each layout?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to have two different fragment with differentLayout and code for only one ?

Comment: yep. where should i put my code?

Comment: i need to show same details when user change the orientation of device .. I have one main activity and two fragment layouts  and classes for portrate mode and landscape mode.  to show same information. where should i put my code ?

Comment: If you want to use Two different fragment then you should put code inside Fragment

Comment: so same code in both fragments? will it cash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put the code where the views are... It's really that simple.

`res/layout-land` should keep the exact same view IDs.

For example, `MainActivity` would load both `res/layout/activity_main.xml` **and** `res/layout-land/activity_main.xml` automatically for you depending on orientation.

`findViewById` will work appropriately if you don't change any ID values

There is a whole [documentation page on this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html). Notice they use retained Fragments, but that is not necessary.

Also [Android Studio: Creating landscape layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28815769/android-studio-creating-landscape-layouts)

Answer (score -1):

Based on Comments what i have understood so far.

You have an activity and you have two fragments. These two fragments have different layouts and you want to show these layouts based on the orientation of the device.

Well there are two approach for this problem

1) You want to achieve this **using fragments**

Create an abstract class for Fragment put common functionality in base class and provide different implementation in different Fragment child class

You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27135199/how-to-show-different-layouts-in-each-tab-in-a-tablayout-using-fragments/43557537#43557537)

2) **Second approach**

It can be achieved in a much simpler way without using fragment. 
Create a **layout-land** directory and put the landscape version of your layout XML file in that directory.

See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124046/how-do-i-specify-different-layouts-for-portrait-and-landscape-orientations) in stackoverflow

Hope it helps.

Comment: I did the second one and it Worked. Thank you Sir1